# How can I use Java 8 Streams with an InputStream?

Tags: java, io, java-8, java-stream

I would like to wrap a `java.util.streams.Stream` around an `InputStream` to process one Byte or one Character at a time. I didn't find any simple way of doing this.

Consider the following exercise: We wish to count the number of times each letter appears in a text file. We can store this in an array so that `tally[0]` will store the number of times a appears in the file, `tally[1]` stores the number of time b appears and so on. Since I couldn't find a way of streaming the file directly, I did this:

```
 int[] tally = new int[26];
 Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Path.get(aFile)).map(s -> s.toLowerCase());
 Consumer<String> charCount = new Consumer<String>() {
   public void accept(String t) {
      for(int i=0; i<t.length(); i++)
         if(Character.isLetter(t.charAt(i) )
            tall[t.charAt(i) - 'a' ]++;
   }
 };
 lines.forEach(charCount);
```

Is there a way of accomplishing this without using the `lines` method? Can I just process each character directly as a Stream or Stream instead of creating Strings for each line in the text file.

Can I more direcly convert `java.io.InputStream` into `java.util.Stream.stream` ?

Comment: Beware! `Character.isLetter` returns `true` for more than just `a-z`, e.g. `ä` or `π`.

Comment: Right, I thought first converting to lower case would take care of that. Maybe I want .isLowerCase?

Comment: No, the point is that Java uses Unicode and there are far more than 26 letters. The conversion to lowercase will do the right thing for them, e.g. convert `'Ä'` to `'ä'` and `'Π'` to `'π'`. But if you want to count the 26 values between `'a'` and `z` only you should filter checking for that range (like I did in my answer) rather than using `isLetter`. `'ä'` and `'π'` *are* lowercase letters…

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First, you have to redefine your task. You are reading *characters*, hence you do not want to convert an `InputStream` but a `Reader` into a `Stream`.

You can’t re-implement the charset conversion that happens, e.g. in an `InputStreamReader`, with `Stream` operations as there can be n:m mappings between the `byte`s of the `InputStream` and the resulting `char`s.

Creating a stream out of a `Reader` is a bit tricky. You will need an iterator to specify a method for getting an item and an end condition:

```
PrimitiveIterator.OfInt it=new PrimitiveIterator.OfInt() {
    int last=-2;
    public int nextInt() {
      if(last==-2 && !hasNext())
          throw new NoSuchElementException();
      try { return last; } finally { last=-2; }
    }
    public boolean hasNext() {
      if(last==-2)
        try { last=reader.read(); }
        catch(IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
      return last>=0;
    }
};
```

Once you have the iterator you can create a stream using the detour of a spliterator and perform your desired operation:

```
int[] tally = new int[26];
StreamSupport.intStream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
  it, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE | Spliterator.NONNULL), false)
// now you have your stream and you can operate on it:
  .map(Character::toLowerCase)
  .filter(c -> c>='a'&&c<='z')
  .map(c -> c-'a')
  .forEach(i -> tally[i]++);
```

---

Note that while iterators are more familiar, implementing the new `Spliterator` interface directly simplifies the operation as it doesn’t require to maintain state between two methods that could be called in arbitrary order. Instead, we have just one `tryAdvance` method which can be mapped directly to a `read()` call:

```
Spliterator.OfInt sp = new Spliterators.AbstractIntSpliterator(1000L,
    Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE | Spliterator.NONNULL) {
        public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer action) {
            int ch;
            try { ch=reader.read(); }
            catch(IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
            if(ch<0) return false;
            action.accept(ch);
            return true;
        }
    };
StreamSupport.intStream(sp, false)
// now you have your stream and you can operate on it:
…
```

---

However, note that if you change your mind and are willing to use `Files.lines` you can have a much easier life:

```
int[] tally = new int[26];
Files.lines(Paths.get(file))
  .flatMapToInt(CharSequence::chars)
  .map(Character::toLowerCase)
  .filter(c -> c>='a'&&c<='z')
  .map(c -> c-'a')
  .forEach(i -> tally[i]++);
```

Comment: The last part of your answer is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't see how to iterate through each String in one line using streams.